# Haskell-Find the shortest word in the list

Tags: haskell

`minimumBy` takes as the first parameter a function that should be used to compare two elements.

`comparing` is a higher-order function that can be used to transform a function of type a -> b(where b is the type that can be compared, i.e. Ord b => a -> b

```
    import Data.List (maximumBy)
    import Data.Ord (comparing)

              findShortestestWord :: String -> String
              findShortestWord s = minimumBy (comparing length) (words s)
```

But an error in the compiler gives

```
"Syntax error in import declaration (unexpected symbol
 "Data.List")"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has wrong indentation, here is working example

```hs
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

findShortestWord :: String -> String
findShortestWord s = minimumBy (comparing length) (words s)

main = getLine >>= print . findShortestWord
```